# too many zeros in my google colaboratory after using imputer and column transformer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

Sorry, I am new in Data science. so I have dataset like this (full code below)

[image]

and then I want to fill the missing data

[image]

as you can see, there is a lot zeros (44.0000000), can I make it just (44.0) ?

```
category = ["Age","Salary"]
imputer_strategy = SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")

imputer = ColumnTransformer([
    ("cat",imputer_strategy,category)
])

X.iloc[:,1:] = imputer.fit_transform(X.iloc[:,1:])
X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this line in your code to get the format you need:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.1f}'.format
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float function.

```
>>> float(44.000000)
```

Output:

```
44.0
```